# AttributeError: type object 'MyUser' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Tags: python, django

I am building a custom User class in django to use in creating a signup application and I keep on getting the error above every time I try to makemigrations. As far as I can see, my code is per django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)..
I also have AUTH_USER_MODEL correctly placed in my settings configurations.
Here's my models.py

```
`class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, 
        first_name,last_name,profile_picture,phone_no,password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            profile_picture=profile_picture,
            phone_no=phone_no,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        SuperUser = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        SuperUser.staff = True
        SuperUser.admin = True
        SuperUser.save(using=self._db)
        return SuperUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = 'email_address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        # validators=email_validator,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number 
    must be entered in the format: '+254 ...'")
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, 
    blank=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',blank=False)
    # email_validator = EmailValidator(message='Invalid email 
    # address',code=None,whitelist=None)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name','phone_no','profile_picture']
    # Email & Password are required by default
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
    def get_short_name():
        return self.email
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
    #does user have a specific permission
        return True
    def has_module_pers(self,app_label):
    #does user have permissions to view the app 'app_label'
        return True
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active


# hook in the New Manager to our Model
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    objects = MyUserManager()
`
```

Comment: Is your multi-line comment not having multiple `#`s a copy-paste error or is that what you're running? You should fix it, it makes your whole script look like a string

Comment: Your class donot have user_name field attribute in it so far from this code....

Comment: @MoxieBall that's a copy-paste error, in my editor the comment is a single line

Comment: You should fix the code in your question

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus is it really a must i have the field user_name? Coz I haven't seen it in the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TO create custom User Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Official Documentation for [CustomUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser)

You are:
 - Extending the base class that Django has for User models.

- Removing the username field.
- Making the email field required and unique.
- List itemTelling Django that you are going to use the email field as the
  USERNAME_FIELD
- Removing the email field from the REQUIRED_FIELDS
  settings (it is automatically included as USERNAME_FIELD)

[Source Link](https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username)

Answer (score 3):

USERNAME_FIELD must be UNIQUE when you create custom User model

So you can just make unique Email field like Roshan says, but some cases Email can not be unique for some services.

So I prefer just make one uuid field and make it USERNAME_FIELD like this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    uid = models.UUIDField(
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        unique=True,
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = "uid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a multiline comment that is ill-formatted

`#email_validator = EmailValidator(message='Invalid email
address',code=None,whitelist=None)`

the second line of that comment is not actually commented so the single quote after address is opening a string that appears to contain the rest of the class and is closed at the stray single quote at the very end.

Comment: that's a copy-paste error, in my editor it's well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working after adding the field also,

check if the value passed is in string format :

Wrong -> `USERNAME_FIELD = email`

Correct -> `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class usertype(models.Model):
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(usertype,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = 1)
```