# I am trying to change to a custom user model, but an error occurs

Tags: django

I'm trying to change the Django user model to a custom user model, but an error occurs

How do I resolve the error? thanks for let me know ~!

step1
settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

step2
accounts/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

step3 When migrating, an error occurs as follows

```
(askcompany) C:\my_django\askcompany>python manage.py makemigrations
```

error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\askcompany\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 39, in check_user_model
    if cls.USERNAME_FIELD in cls.REQUIRED_FIELDS:
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

step4 and I changed to this but another error is occuered

accounts/models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

error message:

```
(askcompany) C:\my_django\askcompany>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\askcompany\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\askcompany\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\askcompany\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup

(askcompany) C:\my_django\askcompany>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
accounts.User: (auth.E003) 'User.email' must be unique 
because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD'.
```

step5
i change to this again

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

another error meesage is this

```
ERRORS:
accounts.User: (auth.E002) The field named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD' for a custom user model must not be included in 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: type object 'MyUser' has no attribute 'USERNAME\_FIELD'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308530/attributeerror-type-object-myuser-has-no-attribute-username-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error clearly states that 'User.email' must be unique. Username can not be duplicate or blank. change your email field as below -

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

and it should work.

Edit -
change your user model as below -

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

If you want to use permissions, I would recommend that you also inherit PermissionsMixin to your user or inherit AbstractUser instead of AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: I changed to this but another error is occuered => 
accounts.User: (auth.E002) The field named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD' for a custom user model must not be included in 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'.

Comment: good it's work it's accurate answer thanks Arvind Kumar

Answer (score 2):

The error says USERNAME_FIELD has no attribute.
So if you don't want a name field you can tell Django that you are going to use the email field as the USERNAME_FIELD like this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

View this document, this will explain more.

https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username

Comment: When I did it this way, I got another error so I updated question

Answer (score 1):

You should be inheriting from **`AbstractUser`**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

If you want to set `email` as the username field, you need to set `unique=True`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: When I did it this way, I got another error so I updated question

Comment: @hyunk what error was that?  It was probably because of preexisting migrations

Comment: @hyunk if you are talking about the error in your edit, see my update for the solution

Comment: So will clearing all the migration files solve the problem?